# Error in running loop code: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, loops

[image: Error in appending the matrix]

I don't understand where is the error and how to resolve it. I tried running this same code lat week and it worked and now I. don't know why this error

Answer (score 0):

`eco.monte_carlo_simulation(10000)` must be returning a `tuple`. You cannot assign a `tuple` to the array position specified by `result[n2-1,n3-1]`, because `result` has been created as a `numpy` array of `float32`